# FileNotFoundException in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, my directory structure is this:

```
-src
 -com.xxx.yyy
  - MyClass.java
-assets
  - car.txt
```

MyClass.java looks like this :

```
public class MyClass {
    private static String FILE_PATH = "../assets/car.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                     //FileNotFoundException
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_PATH)); 
        }
     ...
    }
}
```

I this by default, the classpath is `src/`, so I point to my **car.txt** file by `../assets/car.txt`. But I get :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../assets/car.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

Why ?

Comment: have you tried `"assets/car.txt"`, I think it'll work.

Comment: you could print out the canonicalpath of the File as a kind of debugging - then you might see if the relative path was correct.

Comment: @AnkitLamba, assets/car.txt works! What is the reason behind?

Comment: @user842225 A relative path is relative to the execution location of your program, not your class.  You can use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to see the current directory you are running in or `new File(".").getCanonicalPath()`

Comment: yeah, that's the reason!!!  I think I've missed some repo!!!

Answer (score 3):

Relative file paths a relative to the execution, assuming that the program is executed in the same location as the `src` and `assets` directory, then the path should be  `assets/car.txt`

You can check the current execution location using `System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());`

Answer (score 1):

Whe you run the program it is compiled to the parent folder of the `src` folder as far as I know. You should better add the `assets` folder to your build path and access the file using `getClass().getResource[AsStream]()`.

To add the folder do the following:

```
Right click on your project
Click Build Path
Choose Configure Build Path
Select Source
Click Add Folder...
Select your assets folder
```

Inside your code you can either call it with `MyClass.class.getResource[AsStream]()` or `getClass().getResource[AsStream]()`.

`getResource()` returns an `URL` and `getResourceAsStream()` an `InputStream`. Both methods expect a path as parameter. Check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) for more information.

Comment: But what should I pass to the two methods as parameter?

Comment: They expect the path to the resource as `String`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect

Since you are inside `com.xxx.yyy`, you are inside three folders. You need to get out of all of them.

So you can use, the relative path as

```
FILE_PATH = "../../../assets/car.txt";
```

As src is a `source folder`, all the contents come directly in the classpasth, you can also use

```
FILE_PATH = "assets/car.txt";
```

Comment: Tired, I got the same error for "../../../assets/car.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You are in second level in directory structure.

Try

```
 FILE_PATH = "../../assets/car.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help you...

```
package com.xxx.yyy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class MyClass {
private static String FILE_PATH = "src/assets/car.txt";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
                 //FileNotFoundException
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_PATH)); 
    }
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ankit Lamba 's suggestion works: that's using `String FILE_PATH = "assets/car.txt";`